# Add a previously viewed section to website

Tags: php, sql

The first attempt that I made to add a previously-viewed section to a website:

Upon clicking a listing the photo of the listing, the price, id and title would be inserted into a table called views. The date would get updated automatically from within phpmyadmin to give the time and date that it was clicked. Now to get rid of the duplicate values within the views table:

```
DELETE FROM `views`WHERE date NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(date) as date FROM `views` GROUP BY id, title
    )
```

Then in the section that I need to display the recently viewed:

```
SELECT * FROM views ORDER BY date
```

This works; however it is not a scalable solution.

Another approach that I attempted was to only store the id of the listing, the user logged in and the time the listing was clicked. However, I was not able to sort from the child table:

```
SELECT * FROM listings where id in (
    SELECT id FROM views order by date
    )
```

That won't work because it will not sort based on the views table.

How can I retrieve the data from listings that were previously viewed by users, without duplicating all the the data in another table? I would like to have flexibility and access to this data, so I don't want it to be completely client side; In case later on I want to display different recommendations to users based on what they were viewing. For example, a section on the website that gives recommendations based on what they have been viewing and/or what they have liked.

Comment: Does the "previously viewed" area need to be seen by users other than the current user?  Does it need to persist between devices?  If no, and no, then why not just keep it totally client-side?

Comment: Yeah that is true. However, would it be better to have it in databases so that it would be easier to be able to give suggestions to other users based on what they are liking compared to different users

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LoganM You should update your question with more information as to what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried cookies

Comment: I have updated the question, however I believe that the answer below is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ezw yes I did try cookies, but I want to store all of the previously-viewed permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering "previously viewed" in it's pure form, meaning that you want to display to the user "here are pages you just visited."

To accomplish this, there's no need to muddle the data collected for user tracking (i.e. Google Analytics or a custom interactions tracking) with the enablement of this feature.

Add a script like this to your frontend on page load. I'm writing this on my cell... So please excuse the pseudo code.

```js
const store = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('previouslyViedPages') || '[]')

if (store.indexOf(location.path) == -1) {
  store.unshift(location.path)
  const lastFivePages = JSON.stringify(store.slice(0, 5))
  localStorage.set('previouslyViewedPages', lastFivePages) 
}
```

This approach adds a lot of flexibility with very little overhead. Meanwhile, you can still collect and store all the user tracking metrics, but not have to double your database read volume page load.

Additionally, you can of course add any custom parameters/logic to determine whether or not a page is tracked as previously viewed. For example, maybe you only care about showing previously viewed product pages, and not terms and services pages. This could be easily accomplished by a boolean condition on the URL or an observed query param.

Comment: Just to reiterate, I'm assuming things like enabling a recommendation engine based on other users likes and interactions is a completely different concern that demands an entirely different approach.